# How do I print binary, octal and hexadecimal numeric values in their declared form?

Tags: swift

I'm declaring the following constants and printing their values, but when I print they always print in their decimal form. How do I get them to print in their originally defined form?

```
let binaryInteger = 0b10001
let octalInteger = 0o21
let hexadecimalInteger = 0x11
print("Binary Integer: \(binaryInteger) and in binary \(binaryInteger)")
print("Octal Integer: \(octalInteger) and in octal \(octalInteger)")
print("Hexadecimal Integer: \(hexadecimalInteger) and in hexadecimal \(hexadecimalInteger)")
```

The output I'd like to see for the first print statement would be:

`Binary Integer: 17 and in binary 10001.`

What do I need to put in front of the \( to get it to print in binary/octal/hex?

Comment: Your values don't remember their originally defined form (or radix). Constants expressed in binary, octal, hex, or any other radix get converted to the native format of the type (binary for Integer types) at compile-time, with no information about the source format you use to specify those constants. You'd have to create your own type that wrapped integer types, had separate initializers for each radix, and remembered the radix you used to define them.

Comment: See Sulthan's answer for how you convert Integer values to Strings in different radices .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert the integers to given String representation manually:

```
print("Binary Integer: \(binaryInteger) and in binary \(String(binaryInteger, radix: 2))")
print("Octal Integer: \(octalInteger) and in octal \(String(octalInteger, radix: 8))")
print("Hexadecimal Integer: \(hexadecimalInteger) and in hexadecimal \(String(hexadecimalInteger, radix: 16))")
```

Of course, you might also create custom String interpolation to be able to use something like the following:

```
print("Hexadecimal Integer: \(hexadecimalInteger) and in hexadecimal \(hexadecimalInteger, radix: 16)")
```

See an example [here](https://ericasadun.com/2018/12/14/more-fun-with-swift-5-string-interpolation-radix-formatting/)

Answer (score 1):

Basic answer is given by Silthan, I would also wrap it in the structure, which helps to preserve the original format:

```
enum Radix: Int {
    
    case binary = 2
    case octal = 8
    case hexa = 16
    
    var prefix: String {
        switch self {
        case .binary:
            return "0b"
        case .octal:
            return "0o"
        case .hexa:
            return "0x"
        }
    }
}

struct PresentableNumber<T> where T: BinaryInteger & CustomStringConvertible {
    
    let number: T
    let radix: Radix
    
    var originalPresentation: String {
        return radix.prefix + String(number, radix: radix.rawValue)
    }
}

extension PresentableNumber: CustomStringConvertible {
    
    var description: String {
        return number.description
    }
}
```

This way you can define and print your numbers like this:

```
let binaryInteger = PresentableNumber(number: 0b10001, radix: .binary)
let octalInteger = PresentableNumber(number: 0o21, radix: .octal)
let hexadecimalInteger = PresentableNumber(number: 0x11, radix: .hexa)

print("Binary Integer: \(binaryInteger) and in binary \(binaryInteger.originalPresentation)")
print("Octal Integer: \(octalInteger) and in octal \(octalInteger.originalPresentation)")
print("Hexadecimal Integer: \(hexadecimalInteger) and in hexadecimal \(hexadecimalInteger.originalPresentation)")
```

The output:

```
Binary Integer: 17 and in binary 0b10001
Octal Integer: 17 and in octal 0o21
Hexadecimal Integer: 17 and in hexadecimal 0x11
```